# How do I correctly route FastAPI on AWS Lambda using Mangum to avoid a 'not found' error?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, fastapi, mangum

I have an AWS Lambda function which I can't seem to hook up to a custom domain using AWS API Gateway.  I consistently get a `{"detail":"Not Found"}` error when I curl:

```
https://api.domain.com/api/v1/users
https://api.domain.com/api/v1/users/1
```

I added a catch all to return the method and the request with the code looking like this but I can't see how to match it to the returned url:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from mangum import Mangum

app = FastAPI() # /api/v1/users/


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

@app.get("/users")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "Users"}

@app.get("/users/{user_id}")
def user_item(user_id: int, q: str = None):
    return {"user_id": user_id, "q": q}

# My catch all code
#@app.api_route("/{path_name:path}", methods=["GET"])
#async def catch_all(request: Request, path_name: str):
#    return {"request_method": request.method, "path_name": path_name}

handler = Mangum(app, lifespan="off")
```

Which, when uncommented returns the path_name correctly:

```
{"request_method":"GET","path_name":"api/v1/users"}
{"request_method":"GET","path_name":"api/v1/users/1"}
```

I am totally stuck but I think it's something to do with either a prefix or a default root.

Comment: It's because of `api/v1`. Try setting [`api_gateway_root_path`  in the Mangum app](https://mangum.io/adapter/#configuring-an-adapter-instance).  or set `API_GATEWAY_ROOT_PATH` the corresponding environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So 3 things were required to fix this:

1. Firstly I needed to specify an `api_gateway_base_path='/api/v1/users'` so Mangum knew where the AWS root path of `api.domain.com/api/v1/users` was. This gave me no docs but did allow me to access `/users/` and `/users/whatever`
2. I then needed to specify the `root_path="/api/v1/users"` which then enabled me to access `api.domain.com/api/v1/users/docs`
3. Unfortunately I still had one problem `api.domain.com/api/v1/users` was still "not found". In order to solve this I had to add an additional route `@app.get('', include_in_schema=False)` to capture routes which had no trailing forward slash.  I added the False for include_in_schema so the automatic documentation system wasn't generating the same docs for the same route.

Final code looked like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from mangum import Mangum
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI(
    root_path="/api/v1/users"
)  

@app.get('', include_in_schema=False)
@app.get("/")
def read_root(request: Request):
    return {"Hello": "Users"}



# @app.api_route("/{path_name:path}", methods=["GET"])
# async def catch_all(request: Request, path_name: str):
#     print(request.scope)
#     return {
#         "request_method": request.method,
#         "root_path": request.scope['root_path'],
#         "raw_path": request.scope['raw_path'],
#         "path": request.scope['path'],
#         "path_name": path_name
        
#     }

handler = Mangum(
    app, 
    lifespan="off", 
    api_gateway_base_path='/api/v1/users'
)
```